The word "fudge" and its slightly ambiguous meanings
If I say "We fudged the report" does it mean that we made the report but in a very clumsy\lazy way or that we deliberately falsified the report to make it look better or cover a mistake?

We fabricated data in places.  Possibly someone might use the word fudge where data was omitted as well.  The data, as presented, are intentionally distorted.

Okay, so a combination of the two.
To falsify the report but in a clumsy way, right?

It's possible to use the word "fudge" when the fudging was done in such a way that people might not notice the fudging. So not necessarily clumsy.  But untruthful, at least in part.

Also, to some people, this could mean "screwed it up, did it wrong". But in the context of a report it is likely the "obscured the facts, omitted the context, stretched the interpretation" meaning.

Cambridge's definition is pretty clear:

to cheat about something slightly, esp. by not reporting facts accurately or not telling the exact truth

So it doesn't always mean lying, but it can do. Cheating doesn't necessarily mean presenting lies - for example, someone could cheat on an exam by looking up the right answers. In that case, the cheating is in the method, not the result.
If a report was said to be "fudged" that could suggest different things - either that the report was deliberately altered or the facts skewed to give a false impression, thereby cheating the audience, or perhaps the creators of the report made up for incompetence by saying things they weren't sure of or making up numbers that they hoped might be right, thereby 'cheating' in their methods. In my experience, people sometimes say they "fudged" something if they used a makeshift or less-than-optimum means of achieving it, so it doesn't even have to infer devious means or motives.
